Upgrading to React 18 missing 'onPointerEnterCapture' and 'onPointerLeaveCapture'
I wanted to upgrade my project fronm react 17 to 18 but on updating,
I am getting

Property 'onPointerEnterCapture' is missing in type

Everything works fine if I just give undefined but looks bad.
Any way to fix it without using undefined?
onPointerEnterCapture={undefined}
onPointerLeaveCapture={undefined}

